# JCL to create dataset whether it already exists or not

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

I want to write some JCL to create a dataset, with the requirements that :

1. if the dataset doesn't exist, create it

and either:

2. if the dataset already exists, overwrite it

or

3. if the dataset already exists, do nothing

As I understand it, (1) can be accomplished with DISP=NEW, and (2) with DISP=OLD, but I can't figure out from the docs and my course material how to do both at the same time. NEW throws a JCL error if the dataset exists and OLD throws one if it doesn't. I have no idea how to do (3).

I understand there are ways to query if a dataset exists within JCL, but we haven't covered that yet, so I assume it's possible without?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for a generation data group.  This wouldn't *overwrite* the existing dataset, but would give you a new dataset every time your JCL is executed.

Up front you must create the generation data group base entry with an IDCAMS command documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=commands-define-generationdatagroup).   This is a one time operation.

```
//MAKEGDG1 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
 DEFINE GDG (NAME(MY.DSN) LIMIT(255))
//*
```

To use this, you write JCL such as...

```
//USEGDG1  EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
//DD001    DD  DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//             DSN=MY.DSN(+1),
//             SPACE=(...),
//             and so on
```

...where the `(+1)` means to create a new generation within the group.  What is actually created is a dataset with the name `MY.DSN.G####V00`, where `####` is a sequential number managed for you by the system, but you can always get the most current generation with `MY.DSN(0)`.  You can use the previous to the most current generation with `MY.DSN(-1)`.

Some care is required, if you code `MY.DSN` without specifying a generation number in parens you will get all extant generations.

If a GDG is not what you're looking for, you could also code an IDCAMS step in front of your step cataloging your new dataset.  The purpose of the IDCAMS step would be to delete the dataset.  The IDCAMS `DELETE` command will give you a bad return code (12, if memory serves) if the dataset doesn't exist, but you can modify that by coding `IF MAXCC=12 THEN SET MAXCC=0` under those circumstances.

**Update per additional restrictions on what's allowed**

If what you want is to create the dataset if it doesn't already exist and *append* to it if it does, that can be accomplished with `DISP=(MOD,CATLG)`.  I don't believe there is a way to accomplish your goal as stated without using either IDCAMS or writing a clist or Rexx program that does essentially what the IDCAMS `DELETE` does.

You could code `DISP=(NEW,CATLG)` and let the job fail if the dataset already exists.  It's a *terrible* thing to do, but I think it meets your criteria.

I'm not in a position to test this right now, but you might try...

```
//CKEXIST1 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
//DD001    DD  DISP=OLD,DSN=MY.DSN
//*
//IF001    IF  CKEXIST.RUN=TRUE THEN
//* step with DISP=OLD
//         ELSE
//* step with DISP=NEW
//IF001E   ENDIF
```

...but even if it works I still think it's pretty ugly.  The idea is the IEFBR14 step won't execute because the dataset allocation will fail.  The IF001 statement is checking to see if the step ran, and I *think* that will test false if the dataset doesn't exist and true if it does.  Not something I'd recommend for a production jobstream.

Comment: ah... well, that's an excellent answer, and if no other is proposed I'll surely accept it. Sadly it's not the one I was looking for (although you couldn't know that). Our teacher told us we would learn about IDCAMS latter, so I assume this exercise is meant to be solved without it. Do you happen to have another idea ? =]

Comment: I suddenly realise that it would also be perfectly acceptable to ignore the write step if the file exists, instead of overwriting. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Again, that's very good. I'm starting to think there's something wrong with my exercise, if the only solution is that improper.

Answer (score 4):

Generally I create a step prior to the creation of the dataset to delete the dataset.  Although I use DISP=(MOD,DELETE).  SPACE=(TRK,0) is effectively a null value for space because we’re going to delete the DSN or allocate with no space to delete it anyway.  The difference between this and the answer by @bruce_martin is that the dataset creation is tied to the step actually writing the dataset.

This means that if the file does not exist it is created, if it exists it is used and the DELETE says delete it at step termination.  The net effect is that the DSN is deleted whether it existed or not prior to the next step.

Here is an example,

```
//DEL0010  EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
//DSN2DEL  DD   DSN=dataset.to.write.to,DISP=(MOD,DELETE),
//              SPACE=(TRK,0),UNIT=SYSALLDA
//*
//STEP0010 EXEC PGM=MYPROG
//DSN2CR8  DD   DSN=dataset.to.write.to,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//              SPACE=...,UNIT=...
```

Using this approach ensures there is no dataset for the next step so you don’t have to be concerned with condiditional restarts.

Answer (score 2):

@cschneids is an excellent solution; but to do 1 & 2 you could do

```
//CREATE   EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
//DD001    DD  DISP=(MOD,CATLG,DELETE),
//             DSN=MY.DSN,...
//*
//USEGDG1  EXEC PGM=MYPGM,COND=(0,NE)
//DD001    DD  DISP=OLD,
//             DSN=MY.DSN
```

for option 3 you could use IDCAMS

Answer (score 1):

create a jcl with extra steps (it's 21 years since I wrote JCL so I'll leave the exact coding to you).

```
// step1 exec pgm=idcams
  rename my.dsn in my.otherdsn
/*
//step2 exec pgm=idcams, cond=(0, eq, step1)  rename successful: rename back
 rename my.otherdsn in mydsn
/*
//step3 exec pgm=IEFBR14, cond=(0, ne, step1) did not exist, create it
//mydsn dd my.dsn,disp(new,catlg), etc
/*
//step4a exec pgm=myprogram, parm='EXISTS", cond=(0, eq, step1)
// ....
//step4b exec pgm=myprogram, parm='NEW", cond=(0, ne, step1)
// ....
```

use the parm of myprogram to work out your program logic!

Something like this worked for us too to automatically restore files: first step renames a in b. if this fails, the job had been aborted, so step2 restores the database. then the actual job jcl was included. the last step in the job renames b in a.